# Open new activity if login is successful with jsonObject android

Tags: java, android, json

i am trying to implement login activity on my app but I am not able to start new activity when login is successful.

my code

```
EditText editEmail, editPassword, editName;
Button btnSignIn, btnRegister;

String URL= "http://example.com/ecommerce/user/index.php";

JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();

int i=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    editName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    editPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

    btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
    btnRegister=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AttemptLogin attemptLogin= new AttemptLogin();
                attemptLogin.execute(editName.getText().toString(),editPassword.getText().toString(),"");
            }
        });

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(i==0)
                {
                    i=1;
                    editEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnRegister.setText("CREATE ACCOUNT");
                }
                else{

                    btnRegister.setText("REGISTER");
                    editEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    i=0;

                    AttemptLogin attemptLogin= new AttemptLogin();
                    attemptLogin.execute(editName.getText().toString(),editPassword.getText().toString(),editEmail.getText().toString());

                }

            }
        });


}

private class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    @Override

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {



        String email = args[2];
        String password = args[1];
        String name= args[0];

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        if(email.length()>0)
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);


        return json;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            if (result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

}

i am trying to implement login activity on my app but I am not able to start new activity when login is successful.

i am struggling to start new activity only when `toast` is displaying **Successfully logged in** otherwise failed message is display any idea how can i do that?

Comment: i am creating low budget app so cheaper method is adopted.

Comment: @DudeCoder please answer the above question, sir.

Comment: What are the name of your Activities? The one you have posted your code and the one you want to start?

Comment: This code is correct, right? all thing you should do just add code start activity in method onPostExecute(..), that is very simple so I have some confusion why you need to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible by defining if you get this message so new activity is started try this.

```
try {
            if (result.getString("message").equals("Successfully logged in"))  {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivitySecond.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great library named **Volley** to parse JSON result and would help you with login functionality. I am sharing an official documentation on Volley that would give you a brief idea and usage and for further use, there is a link to the tutorial which helps you understand how to use it.

[Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/)

[Tutorial Link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-fetch-json/)